# Rails - background job with guaranteed sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best approach to make sure specific background jobs (DelayedJob, or Resque) are executed sequentially, instead of in parallel? I guess one option is to have a dedicated queue and assign one worker only to the queue. Is there a better approach?

Comment: You could schedule the next job at the end of the first job, and so on. "Best approach" is an opinion-based question though, and not suitable for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I did some background job functions using ActiveJob & Resque before.

I think do it by checking and setting status(e.g. pending, in-progress ..) 
for each job.

And passing it for background jobs one by one.